# Prolog add elements

Tags: prolog

My problem is:

> Write a Prolog program that, given two lists L1 and L2
>   , outputs
>   two new lists L3 and L4
>   such that L3 contains the elements of
>   L1 which also belong to L2
>   , while L4 contains the elements
>   of L1 which do not belong to L2
>   . You may use the built-in
>   predicate member.
>   As an example, the query listmem([a, r, t], [t, s, m, n, a], L3, L4)
>   produces L3 = [a, t] and L4 = [r].

And my solution is now:

```
memberOf([], [], _).
memberOf([H|T], L2, [X|Xs]) :-
   X is H,
   member(X, L2),
   memberOf(T, L2, Xs).
```

But when I test on the following input, it returns no..

> memberOf( [1,2,3], [2,3,4], L3 ).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use `is/2` here as it is intended for arithmetic expression evaluation. `is/2` will happen to work with numbers this way, but not on atoms. Use unification `=/2`. What is happening here, though, as far as why you're getting "no" is that your recursion continues to reduce the first argument list down to `[]`, but the second argument is never reduced to `[]`. So your base case will never match and eventually, since the first argument becomes `[]` and doesn't match the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
listmem(L1,[],[],L1).
listmem([],_,[],[]).
listmem([H1|T1],L2,[H1|L3],L4):-
    member(H1,L2), !,
    listmem(T1,L2,L3,L4). 
listmem([H1|T1],L2,L3,[H1|L4]):-
    listmem(T1,L2,L3,L4).
```

I've added a cut to the third case instead of a `\+ member(H1,L2)` to the last one so you can use `listmem` the "other way around", e.g., instead of:

```
?- listmem([a, r, t], [t, s, m, n, a], L3, L4).
L3 = [a, t],
L4 = [r].
```

You can also:

```
?- listmem([a, r, t], L2, [a,t], L4).
L2 = [a, t|_G10554000],
L4 = [r].
```